# Mage report showing security patch SUPEE8788 is not patched but i have copied all files to magento root

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches

Mage report showing security patch `SUPEE8788` is not patched but I have copied all files to Magento root.

I have download zip of `SUPEE8788` and extract into Magento root and delete swf files from skin folder as directed on mage report and other sites.

Please help me for above issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: NO. That wont works. YOu need to install it, not replace the files.

Answer (score 1):

Installation of any patch in Magento system is easy:

**To install 8788 v2 patch** just follow below steps:

1. Download 8788 v2 patch .sh file from https://magento.com/tech-resources/downloads/magento/
2. Put this patch file in Magento root directory.
3. Now go to root directory via SSH
4. INSTALL PATCH: via `sh PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v2-2016-10-14-09-42-47.sh`
5. Clear Caches: `rm -rf var/cache/*`

**Note:** There are some problem while reverting this patch. But using GIT its possible via command `git revert COMMIT_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run that patches copy & paste it's not enough

For more please check this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html